# File is both a regular file and a symlink

Tags: shell, zsh, symlink

I have three files, one a real ("regular") file and two chained symlinks:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff       24  4 Nov 18:23 A
lrwxr-xr-x   1 user  staff        1 25 Oct 17:43 B -> A
lrwxr-xr-x   1 user  staff        1  4 Nov 16:54 C -> B
```

Now, using `zsh` conditional expressions (`[[`), I test whether `B` (or `C`) is a regular file or a symlink, and `zsh` says yes to both ...:

```
18:31 : [[ -f B ]] && echo "True"
True
18:31 : [[ -h B ]] && echo "True"
True
```

Isn't a symlink supposed *not to be* a regular file? `zsh` documentation of conditional expressions ([here](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Conditional-Expressions.html)) doesn't give full details on how different cases work.

```
zsh --version
zsh 5.0.5 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0)
```

**edit**

After more digging, I found this Q&A on Unix.SE : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22009/distinguishing-a-regular-file-from-a-symlink. It's about `bash` but it looks like it also applies to `zsh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zsh is almost certainly using the `S_ISREG()` and `S_ISLNK()` macros from [`lstat(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/lstat).  Since `S_ISLNK()` is younger than `S_ISREG()`, I imagine symlinks were historically treated like regular files here (since they aren't directories, block/character devices, etc.), and the behavior was kept for backwards compatibility.  I wasn't able to find any direct evidence of this, however.